# Database initialization error in static method

Tags: android

I have database class. The class and its constructor are shown below.

```
    public class LatLogDBAdapter {   

     private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

          DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
              super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
          }
}
```

I want to use the database in the static method. So that I declare as `private static LatLogDBAdapter dbHelper;`. Then when i initialize, i have problem. `dbHelper = new LatLogDBAdapter(this);` `dbHelper = new LatLogDBAdapter(DetailMapView.this);` make compile error. How can I use this in static method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create static method that returns your dbhelper i suggest you to create normal subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` and in this class create public static method that will return new instance. This also is sounds like good reason to use design pattern `Singleton`

### Update:

> I mean I want to use this database class inside another java class.
>   That class has static method and use the database.

Here i create for you basic snippet of code:

```
public class AdapterWrapper {

    private static SQLiteOpenHelper instance;

    public static SQLiteOpenHelper getInstance(Context c) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(c);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DB_NAME = "Example";
        private static final int DB_START_VERSION = 1;

        public DatabaseHelper(Context cntx) {
            super(cntx, DB_NAME, null, DB_START_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // creating tables
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int old, int new) {
            /// drop an upgrading db
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean I want to use this database class inside another java class. That class has static method and use the database.

Comment: So you can also have it as inner class and then just create variable of your inner class in parent class and static method that returns instance of inner class.

Comment: @Bryanyan answer updated check it out(morning i was on phone so i couldn't write you some java code).

Comment: Thanks Sajmon, but I think I can't present the problem clearly. Let me post the query in a new thread.